# import excel file to database using EPPlus

Tags: asp.net, excel, import, epplus

I am having a hard time understanding what should be a simple task. I am now using EPPlus to help me with this task. However, I am at a point of where I can't track what is going on. (per the comment below and days of google searching) I'm trying to read in an excel file and pass that to my EF model. It breaks down at line 159 where I am trying to put in the values from the excel file but keeps coming across as null. However when looking at the values past line 159 they all have the correct information. I am not sure how to even track a bug like this.

TruckController.cs

```
    // POST: Trucks/Import
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Import(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        if (Request != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["file"];


            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/" + "test.xlsx"));
                //string fileName = file.FileName;
              //  string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
               // var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
                var MyImport = new List<string>();
               MyImport = ImportDataRecords(new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/" ) + "test.xlsx"));
            }
        }
        return View("Import");
    }

    public List<string> ImportDataRecords(FileInfo file)
    {
        var resultMessages = new List<string>();
        var totalImported = 0;
        try
        {
            using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(file))
            {
                string DeliveryColumn,
                    ItemNoColumn,
                    MaterialColumn,
                    MaterialDescriptionColumn,
                    DeliveryQtytoPickColumn,
                    PickedQuantityColumn,
                    SalesUoMColumn,
                    BatchPickedColumn,
                    BinNoColumn,
                    BagWeightColumn,
                    PalletNoColumn,
                    PalletStackingNoColumn,
                    StageNoColumn,
                    SubStopNoColumn,
                    PickStatusColumn,
                    PackStatusColumn,
                    SoldToColumn,
                    SoldToNameColumn,
                    ShipToNameColumn;

                if (!file.Name.EndsWith("xlsx"))
                {
                    resultMessages.Add("File selected is not an Excel file");
                    return resultMessages;
                }

                var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                if (worksheet == null)
                {
                    resultMessages.Add("File was empty");
                    return resultMessages;
                }

                using (var headers = worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, worksheet.Dimension.End.Column])
                {
                    var expectedHeaders = new[]
                    {
                        "Delivery", "Item No.", "Material", "Material Description", "Delivery Qty to Pick",
                        "Picked Quantity", "Sales UoM", "Batch Picked", "BIN No.", "Bag Weight", "Pallet No.",
                        "Pallet Stacking No", "Stage No", "Sub Stop No", "Pick Status", "Pack Status", "Sold-To",
                        "Sold-To Name", "Ship-To Name"
                    };
                    if (!expectedHeaders.All(e => headers.Any(h => h.Value.Equals(e))))
                    {
                        resultMessages.Add("Some columns are missing from the file");
                        return resultMessages;
                    }

                    DeliveryColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Delivery")).Address[0].ToString();
                    ItemNoColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Item No.")).Address[0].ToString();
                    MaterialColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Material")).Address[0].ToString();
                    MaterialDescriptionColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Material Description")).Address[0].ToString();
                    DeliveryQtytoPickColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Delivery Qty to Pick")).Address[0].ToString();
                    PickedQuantityColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Picked Quantity")).Address[0].ToString();
                    SalesUoMColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Sales UoM")).Address[0].ToString();
                    BatchPickedColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Batch Picked")).Address[0].ToString();
                    BinNoColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("BIN No.")).Address[0].ToString();
                    BagWeightColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Bag Weight")).Address[0].ToString();
                    PalletNoColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Pallet No.")).Address[0].ToString();
                    PalletStackingNoColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Pallet Stacking No")).Address[0].ToString();
                    StageNoColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Stage No")).Address[0].ToString();
                    SubStopNoColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Sub Stop No")).Address[0].ToString();
                    PickStatusColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Pick Status")).Address[0].ToString();
                    PackStatusColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Pack Status")).Address[0].ToString();
                    SoldToColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Sold-To")).Address[0].ToString();
                    SoldToNameColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Sold-To Name")).Address[0].ToString();
                    ShipToNameColumn = headers.First(h => h.Value.Equals("Ship-To Name")).Address[0].ToString();

                    using (var context = new EPPlusTruckContext())
                    {

                        var lastRow = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                        for (var row = 2; row <= lastRow; row++)
                        {
-----------Line 159-------------> var truck = new Truck()
                            {
                                Delivery = worksheet.Cells[DeliveryColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                ItemNo = worksheet.Cells[ItemNoColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                Material = worksheet.Cells[MaterialColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                MaterialDescription = worksheet.Cells[MaterialDescriptionColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                DeliveryQtyToPick = worksheet.Cells[DeliveryQtytoPickColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                PickedQuantity = worksheet.Cells[PickedQuantityColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                SalesUoM = worksheet.Cells[SalesUoMColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                BatchPicked = worksheet.Cells[BatchPickedColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                BinNo = worksheet.Cells[BinNoColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                BagWeight = worksheet.Cells[BagWeightColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                PalletNo = worksheet.Cells[PalletNoColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                PalletStackingNo = worksheet.Cells[PalletStackingNoColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                StageNo = worksheet.Cells[StageNoColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                SubStopNo = worksheet.Cells[SubStopNoColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                PickStatus = worksheet.Cells[PickStatusColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                PackStatus = worksheet.Cells[PackStatusColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                SoldTo = worksheet.Cells[SoldToColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                SoldToName = worksheet.Cells[SoldToNameColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                                ShipToName = worksheet.Cells[ShipToNameColumn + row].Value.ToString(),
                            };

                                db.Trucks.Add(truck);

                            try
                            {
                                db.SaveChanges();
                                totalImported++;
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                                resultMessages.Add(string.Format("Record on line#{0} failed: {1}\n", row, ex.Message));
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
                resultMessages.Insert(0, string.Format("{0} records successfully imported.\n", totalImported));
                return resultMessages;
            }

        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            resultMessages.Add("File still open. Please close Excel file before importing.");
            return resultMessages;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Clearly `C:\Users\sean\Source\Repos\App\ImportToExcel\ImportToExcel\ContentC:\Users\sean\Downloads\attachments\804272845\804272845.xlsx` is an invalid path.

Comment: Yes but how does one get a clean path? Is this occurring because of the IE browser and if so, can one get just a clean path without having to code for type browser version and such? or how can this be improved. Would I go with a Path.Combine()?

Comment: A website should not be retrieving files directly from the file system of the user machine. That would only work if your server and client are the same machine. Instead, I believe you should be able to get the actual contents of the file from `Request.Files`

Comment: Interesting. I will look into this. Would you have any references on how to go about that methodology?

Comment: A little Googling [would do you some good](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/).

Comment: by all means, I am...just asking because I respect the expertise here at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example here:
Reff: http://sforsuresh.in/read-data-excel-sheet-insert-database-table-c/

```
public bool readXLS(string FilePath)
{
    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(FilePath);
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        //get the first worksheet in the workbook
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  //get Column Count
        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;     //get row count
        string queryString = "INSERT INTO tableName VALUES";        //Here I am using "blind insert". You can specify the column names Blient inset is strongly not recommanded
        string eachVal = "";
        bool status;
        for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
        {
            queryString += "(";
            for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
            {
                eachVal = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString().Trim();
                queryString += "'" + eachVal + "',";
            }
            queryString = queryString.Remove(queryString.Length - 1, 1);    //removing last comma (,) from the string
            if (row % 1000 == 0)        //On every 1000 query will execute, as maximum of 1000 will be executed at a time. 
            {
                queryString += ")";
                status = this.runQuery(queryString);    //executing query
                if (status == false)
                    return status;
                queryString = "INSERT INTO tableName VALUES";
            }
            else
            {
                queryString += "),";
            }
        }
        queryString = queryString.Remove(queryString.Length - 1, 1);    //removing last comma (,) from the string
        status = this.runQuery(queryString);    //executing query
        return status;
    }
}
```